# Ruby on Rails variable visibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, parameters, parameter-passing

I have many controllers where I set variables so that the appropriate views gain visibility to these variables. For example,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
def index
  @users = User.all
end
...
```

This works. So how come this doesn't work:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
...
def show
  @params = params
end
...
```

If I byebug in the show-method, I can access params. If I byebug in the view (places/show.html.erb), then "params" and "@params" return nil.

Does this have something to do with the fact that "User" is an ActiveRecord and "Place" is not? How can I make arbitrary data accessible to the view?

Comment: You do not need to create a new variable `@params`, because `params` is available in the views as well.

Comment: When I try to use params in the view, it returns nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your controller instance variable `@params` in your `/places` views. But because you did not pass any params, `params` returns `nil`.
So, if this variables was out visibility, you would get `NameError`.
Try to set `@params` directly like `@params = { foo: "bar" }` and you will see it.
More about params in Rails [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) (#4 Parameters).

Comment: This should not happen, because `params` always contains `:controller` and `:action`, even if you do not pass any params. There should be an error somewhere. `params` is always a `Hash` and cannot be `nil`.